# How to sort subset of DataView?

Tags: ado.net, dataview

How to sort **subset** of DataView? I use Sort property of DataView. Is it possible to sort all records except last added (let's name it "**new record**") - waiting until user complete entering data in fields of this new record and then initiating sort of the **whole** DataView.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while and you've moved on.  But for future generations, if you use DataView.NewRow() and before you do Row.EndEdit() you can get the other rows by setting your DataView.RowStateFilter to DataViewRowState.OriginalRows.

You retain the new row, can work with those that match the filter.  I would imagine that you then set the filter back to current before doing Row.EndEdit() but I've never done this particular move.

You can also use DataView.Table.NewRow().  This won't be added to your dataview until you perform DataView.Table.Rows.Add(Row).  That is how I always do it - I think it is easier.